# Two fields in List labelField

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I work with Flex and I have made a list and I have a database with a xml file. I give the list a labelField.

I don't know how to write 2 fields into the list. I just can write only one field to the list.

How do I put in list two label Fields this my code:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayList;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        import spark.components.ViewMenu;
        import spark.components.supportClasses.TextBase;
        import spark.components.supportClasses.ViewNavigatorAction;
        import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

        protected function view1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            for (var i:int = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            {
                if (String(arr.getItemAt(i).RestaurantsKuwaiti) == "undefined" || String(arr.getItemAt(i).RestaurantsKuwaiti) == "[object Object]")
                {
                    arr.removeItemAt(i).RestaurantsKuwaiti;
                    i--;
                }
            }
            lst.labelField = "ID"
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Model id="my"
              source="kaka/nndata.xml" />
    <s:ArrayCollection id="arr"
                       source="{my.alldata}" />
</fx:Declarations>

<s:List id="lst"
        left="10"
        right="10"
        top="99"
        bottom="10"
        dataProvider="{arr}"
        fontSize="30"
        fontWeight="bold"
        textAlign="right" />
```

I need help to know how to put 2 fields in one list.

Comment: If I understand the question; you can create a custom itemRenderer or use a labelFunction to display two fields from objects contained in the List's dataProvider.

Answer (score 1):

Use [labelFunction](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dpcontrols_2.html)

`list.labelFunction = lblFunct;`

```
private function lblFunct(value:Object):String
{
   return value.Prop1 + " " + value.Prop2;
}
```